# Is it possible to select all results in Views bulk actions form?

Tags: views, 8, actions

By all results I mean even those that are not displayed on the current page(if there is paging).

Comment: Yes - please see this page on Drupal Gardens support for more information: [Applying bulk actions to view items](http://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/applying-bulk-actions-view-items). In the Views Bulk Operations views field settings, there should be a checkbox allowing you to "Select all items on all pages".

Comment: Thanks. Seems this feature is not yet available in D8.

Comment: Ah, didn't notice the 8 tag; most little things like this in D8 are partially implemented or broken right now; but if you search the issue queue and don't see another note about it, you might want to ask on IRC or add an issue to see if the feature could be added (or if it will be added in a new contrib project).

Comment: it is sad that drupal gardends not just wrote documentation on drupal.org and linked to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple bulk action support in Drupal 8 core does not currently support this feature.

Comment: Yeah bulk operations in core are basically just a poor man version of it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue about [Port Views Bulk Operations to Drupal 8](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations/issues/1823572) is closed (completed) now.

If somebody has problem with it, try to use /admin/yourpath in views, then you use admin theme and select/deselect all button should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you need "select all" you can use the module [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).
Then you can replace the field "Node: Views bulk operation" with the "Global: Views bulk operations" which supports selecting all rows.

Answer (score 0):

This page explains how to enable the "Select All" function: https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/views-bulk-operations-vbo/setting-up-site-administrators

TL;DR with VBO enabled, go to the view and replace the `User: Bulk update` or `Content: Node operations bulk form` with the `Global: Views bulk operations` field.